# Laravel , parámetro en una función

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php7, php5, laravel-4

Tengo esta función ,la idea es crear un objeto del tipo Classroom y pasarselo a un servicio para que haga la lógica correspondiente

```
public function index()
{
    $data = [
        'user_id' => '1',
        'name' => test test test',
        'description' => 'test',
    ];

    $classroom = new Classroom();
    $classroom->create($data);

    ClassroomService::calculateNewClassroom($classroom);
}
```

Hasta aquí me ha creado el objeto Classroom y lo envia como parametro a la función "calculateNewClassroom" donde la tengo definida de esta forma

```
public static function calculateNewClassroom(Classroom $classroom)
{
     dump($classroom);
}
```

Este dump me devuelve vacio , pero en la primera función cuando hago el create de "classroom" veo como los datos se ponen en la tabla correspondiente , por lo que me crea el objeto y lo guarda en la base de datos.

Mi pregunta es , en esta segunda función cuando paso el parámetro le debo indicar que es de tipo classroom? es una buena praxis?

En ambos casos he probado a poner lo o no  y el dump me aparece vacio.

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Problema:
El problema es que en el código de la función `index()` creas un objeto vacío, luego creas un nuevo registro en la base de datos de ese modelo pero no lo recibes en ningún lado

Solución:
utiliza la clase directamente para crear el nuevo objeto con sus datos y utiliza la variable para recibir este objeto en vez del nuevo objeto vacío

```
public function index()
{
    $data = [
        'user_id' => '1',
        'name' => test test test',
        'description' => 'test',
    ];

    $classroom = Classroom::create($data);

    ClassroomService::calculateNewClassroom($classroom);
}
```

Comment: Con esta sintaxis me da error en la linia  $classroom = new Classroom::create($data); ==> error "expected semicolon"

Comment: ah error mio se me olvido borrar la palabra "new " lo edito ahora(listo)

Comment: Perfecto muy amable , de todas formas ahora cuando estoy en la función "calculatenewclassroom" si hago un dump de classrom me hace un print de un objeto vacio.

Comment: puedes mostrar tu modelo y tu miracion, sin eso no puedo darte mas informacion

Comment: y el service tambien porfavor